# Apache Shiro INI entries from database

Tags: shiro

I am working on a project that uses Shiro INI for configurations, some of the configuration entries seem repetitive and would be better stored in a database instead. Is it possible to define the configurations that are typically in the Shiro ini files in a database?

Comment: Can you give an example of the configuration you want to move to a DB?